# how do you trust expired SSL/TLS certificate on Windows?

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate

I have an internal HTTPS-only site with an expired SSL/TLS certificate.

Although I could bypass expired certificates from web browsers, there are other client applications that require a valid certificate or can't be disabled manually.

I need to trust these expired certificates from my local machine.

Is it possible from the Windows certificate manager?

FWIW, I am trying to connect the Sonarqube server (with an expired certificate) from Visual studio 2019. From what I have seen, VS2019 doesn't have any settings to disable certificate checks.

Comment: You install the expired unrevoked certificate into the user's and machine's certificate store.  However, that doesn't necessarily mean your browser, will be happy about the expired certificate. Visual Studio to my knowledge use's the certificate store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. Expired means expired, whether the certificate is trusted or not. Only if software has an explicit "make it insecure" function (like browsers do) can you chose to ignore this.

There can only be one solution, which is exceedingly trivial, too: Update the certificate. You can create a new self-signed certificate with any validity in seconds.

Comment: Problem is, I don't have access to this server and the DevOps personal is so lazy. If this is not possible, I would rather swallow and end trying than make a move. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @wenn32 Lazy? Sounds like passing it higher up the hierarchy could solve this problem. ;-)